# Intersection of Borel subset with line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, descriptive-set-theory

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $A$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $$A(y) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}| (x,y) \in A\}$$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

I think that I have to show that $A(y)$ is in Borel-sigma algebra in $\mathbb{R}$. But the sigma algebra itself has no clear form, I mean I just know that it is the sigma algebra generated by all open sets, there is no clear form of its elements. Another thing is I am not sure if Borel "subset" means the same as Borel 'set' (which simply mean it is in the Borel sigma algebra). Any idea or hint about how to begin ? It is very good if anyone can list some important steps in proving this statement.

Answer (score 2):

Borel subset does mean the same as Borel set.

You can prove the statement by considering the set $M = \{ A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2\,|\, \forall y\in\mathbb{R} \ A(y) \ \text{is Borel}\}$ and showing that $M$ contains all open sets and $M$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Then $M$ must contain all Borel sets, because the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets.${}$

Comment: That method won't work - the result that was requested is not correct, actually.

Comment: @Carl Mummert: Please have a look at the question again. It isn't asking about the projection of the Borel set, but about the sets $A(y)$ for various $y\in\mathbb{R}$, there is a difference.

Comment: I did misread that. There is an alternate, easier proof in that case: just intersect $A$ with a vertical line, and the result will be a Borel set. I had to make a meaningless edit to the answer to make it possible to vote on it again. Thanks for the polite correction.

Comment: Right, it is a bit easier to start with closed sets rather than with open for the proof, so I changed that.

Comment: Shouldn't the defintion be $M=\{A \subset \mathbb {R}^2 : A(y) \text { is a Borel subset of } \mathbb {R}\}?$

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for telling me, I corrected it.

Comment: Actually, now I think the version with starting with open cubes is the easiest. The thing about the title is that $A(y)$ is not actually intersection with a line (that would be trivially Borel), but intersection followed by projection to one of the coordinates, which is definitely more subtle. This kind of measurability result is needed for the statement of the Fubini Theorem.

Comment: @user35359 I try to understand the point of the proof. I do not get the idea of defining $$M = \{A \subseteq \mathbb{R} : A(y) \ \mbox{is a Borel subset of} \ \mathbb{R}\}.$$ I think that I want to prove that $$A(y) \ \mbox{is a Borel subset of real number}.$$ Why don't we instead define $$M = \{A(y) | A \ \mbox{is a Borel subset in} \ \mathbb{R}^2\}$$ and show that this family is a sigma-algebra containing all open intervals in $\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @user35359 I try to find more information and find this  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34142/projection-of-borel-set-from-r2-to-r1

Comment: It seems that the statement is false. I am a bit confusing,

Comment: If you prove that (in your first comment), you prove that each Borel set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is of type $A(y)$ for some Borel set $A$ and $y\in \mathbb{R}$. That's not the same as proving that each $A(y)$ is Borel. The point of my proof is to show that every Borel set $A$ is an element of $M$. Then by definition of $M$, it follows that $A(y)$ is Borel for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Here is another proof: Given $A$ Borel and $y\in\mathbb{R}$ consider the function $x\mapsto (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. It is continuous. Then if you know that the preimage of a Borel set is Borel, you are also done.

Comment: The statement in that link is a different one. If $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ is Borel, then it is not in general true that 
$\{ x\in \mathbb{R} \, |\, \exists y\in \mathbb{R} (x,y)\in A\}$ is Borel.
The proof is not (very) simple.
But it is true that for any specific $y\in \mathbb{R}$ the set
$\{ x\in \mathbb{R} \, |\,  (x,y)\in A\}$
is Borel. Do you see the difference?

Comment: @user35359 For the first one, $y$ is not fix, But for the last one, $y$ is already fixed. Like $A = \{(1,2),(2,3),(3,3)\}$. Then $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \mbox{there exists} \ y \in \mathbb{R}\ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{1, 2, 3\}$, fix $y = 3, A(y) = \{2, 3\}$. Is this what are you trying to point out ?

Comment: Yes, that's it.